# ASP.NET Custom Content Negotiation

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to modify the response, based on the requested content type (check if it's JSON) before it gets returned by the web api. But I can't figure out which is the best way to do it?

In MVC I ca use IsAjaxRequest but in ASP.NET Web Api?

This is my approach:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web.Http
Imports System.Net.Http.Headers

Namespace Controllers.Api
    Public Class DefaultController
        Inherits ApiController

        <HttpGet>
        Public Function ItemLookUp(Optional id As String = "")
            If Request.Headers.Accept.Contains(New MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")) Then
                ... Doing my modification ...
            Else
                Return data
            End If
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Hi @stare can you explain your requirement as to why you need to check if it is json? Ideally you would accept a strongly typed object and modify that object, hence allowing your API user ultimate flexibility to use json, xml, bson etc etc

Comment: It's a client requirement that if the request is for JSON the returned data needs some modifications. All other requests must be returned as is.